# Stop scrolling animation at a set width

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, containers

I have added buttons to a TV guide I am creating to show the next/previous hours listings, however when i click on next it continues to scroll forever. Is there any way to cap this to stop after about 1500px?

Below is the code I am using for the next/previous buttons:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $item = $('.timeCell, .cellProgram'), //Cache your DOM selector
        visible = 2, //Set the number of items that will be visible
        index = 0, //Starting index
        endIndex = ( $item.length / visible ) - 1; //End index

    $('#arrowR').click(function(){
        if(index < endIndex ){
          index++;
          $item.animate({'left':'-=100px'});
        }
    });

    $('#arrowL').click(function(){
        if(index > 0){
          index--;            
          $item.animate({'left':'+=100px'});
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: use max-width in css  or change max-width using js

Comment: Can you set up a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Sure, i have set it up here - http://jsfiddle.net/atdL9tsx/ however the scrolling on the button click seems to be stopping at 4pm. This is not the case so i added overflow scroll, it continues to scroll for as long as you want to click next in my website. Let me know if you have any advice please